# configuring docker container ip for redis host

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I'm trying to configure redis for docker using docker-compose.
So the redis container is running, If I want to connect to the container that has redis running in nodeJs server, what ip address should i use?

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
aa3adc6041aa        redis               "docker-entrypoint..."   About an hour ago   Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   redis

$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' redis
172.18.0.2
```

Does this mean that I should set the env redis host variable to 172.18.0.2? will the variable change on a different machine?

Answer (score 3):

You want to avoid using ip addresses, because they will differ between machine *and between different runs of your docker-compose environment*.

If you are starting your containers using `docker-compose`, then you can refer to other containers in the same file by name.  In other words, if you have:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis

  nodejs_app:
    image: myapp
```

Then you can just set your redis host variable to `redis`.

Comment: I have docker-compose.yml setup like that. I guess my real question was, in my server i have const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient(), I have to put the container ip in there, and was wondering how I can refer to the container ip address

Comment: Are you sure you can't just use a hostname? That's quite common. If you can't, then look up the IP address associated with the name "redis" using, eg, some analog of gethostbyname.